# OSMDROID - How to select the best tiles provider depending on the usage policy

Tags: android, openstreetmap, osmdroid

I am currently developing an **Android app** which will show online maps relating to point of interests nearby the current location of end-users. I am using osmdroid, osmdroidbonuspack and **MAPNIK** as tile provider.

My main concern is the tiles providers' usage policy as I would like to avoid the "forbidden" responses when users start using the app. I don't expect to have too many users but just in case.

Checking the **OSM (MAPNIK)** usage policy, it says that it is not allow to use the maps in an app that is distributed without prior permission. I asked for that permission but in case I did not get it, I was thinking to use **MAPQUEST** maps so I registered in mapquest website to get a private key to be used in the app. The problem is that I don't see any way to add the **MAPQUEST KEY** when using osmdroid.

Summarising I have two questions:

- What is the best tile provider in terms of usage policy to publish an android app?
- In case to select **MAPQUEST**, how can I add a private key? Why does it not required to add a **MAPQUEST** key when using **MAPQUESTOSM**? Is completely open free?

Thank you very much,
Regards,

Answer (score 0):

Since you're talking about OSM, I assume you are referring to MapQuest Open (OSM-based), not standard MapQuest (proprietary data).

MapQuest Open doesn't require a dev key for tile download. You just specify the base URL for MapQuest and you're ready to go. Details can be found on the [OSM Wiki](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/MapQuest#MapQuest-hosted_map_tiles).

MapQuest has asked to be notified by devs who intend to deploy anything that might request larger volumes of tiles. For an app, this obviously depends on the user base. Back when I built MapQuest tile support into my own app, I notified them and asked if they needed anything else for me, and I was simply told to go ahead – no further steps required.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I just checked the OSM wiki and it seems there is no support from MapQuest as the links return 404 - Page not found. I asked to MapQuest and they told me the email support is only provided to paying enterprise customers. Anyway, it looks they are going to change the open maps policy in shorlty.

Comment: MapQuest are currently outsourcing their tile services to MapBox.

Comment: Oddly, Mapquest tiles still work in my app, and I didn't touch the URLs after the initial implementation...

Comment: Yep, it looks the policy will be changing within the next weeks but that does not mean maps won't work. I'm just looking for the best option for the future as so far Mapbox looks it's the best for me.

Answer (score 0):

The [tile usage policy](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Tile_usage_policy) wiki page already lists several [alternative OSM tile providers](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Tile_usage_policy#Alternative_OpenStreetMap_Tile_Providers). The best one depends on your specific requirements.

Comment: Thanks Scai, I already checked those options and asked OpenStreetMaps team (no answer yet) and MapQuest team which only provides help for paying users. I'm currently checking Mapbox. As far as I got checked all those providers I will update my question with my own experience.